# Page reloads after setting state and instead of new state it goes back to initial state

Tags: reactjs, react-state-management, react-state

I am having an issue whenever I click on add button it should generate new field and update state. but as soon as I hit Add button it set the new state and adds the field but then it renders again and goes back to the initial state automatically. What I am doing wrong.

Refer to the code link below

https://codesandbox.io/s/react-hooks-usestate-1h8cw?file=/src/index.js

Comment: Set the `type` attribute of the button to `button` value. By default it has `submit` value. It should be `<button type="button">`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
  const handleAddInput = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault()
    setContacts([...Contacts, { service: "", contact: "" }]);
    // const list = [...Contacts];
    // list.push({ service: "", contact: "" });
    // setContacts(list);
  };
```

because your button submit the form . Add e.preventDefault() to prevent it